# set format with printf for $0

Tags: awk, text-formatting, printf

I compute the row average of the following data set however I have trouble setting the correct format for $0 so as to produce the file-output presented below. I currently have:

```
awk '{T=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) T+=$i; T/=NF; printf "??f 6.3f\n",$0,T}' fileinput > fileoutput
```

file input

```
1   2   3   4
3   3   8   8
5   4   13  12
7   5   18  16
9   6   23  20
11  7   28  24
13  8   33  28
15  9   38  32
17  10  43  36
19  11  48  40
21  12  53  44
23  13  58  48
25  14  63  52
```

desire file output

```
1   2   3   4   2.5
3   3   8   8   5.5
5   4   13  12  8.5
7   5   18  16  11.5
9   6   23  20  14.5
11  7   28  24  17.5
13  8   33  28  20.5
15  9   38  32  23.5
17  10  43  36  26.5
19  11  48  40  29.5
21  12  53  44  32.5
23  13  58  48  35.5
25  14  63  52  38.5
```

Comment: what about `"%s %.1f\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting string for `awk` `printf()` follows the same conventions as for C `printf()`, so in principle

```
awk '{T=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) T+=$i; T/=NF; printf "%s%s%6.3f\n",$0,OFS,T}' fileinput > fileoutput
```

should work.

The minimal change necessary to your current attempt is to state

```
printf "%s %6.3f\n",$0,T
```

but I propose to separate `$0` and `T` using the actual value of the output field separator `OFS` just in case it isn't a single space, but a `TAB` or something else.

Comment: sorry it's fine I had some weird spaces in my input file after fixing them it was absolutely fine! thanks!!

Comment: Ok, you had me worried there for a moment ;)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly alternate `awk`

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}{s=$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; $(NF+1)=sprintf("%.1f", s/NF)}1' file
```

Maintain the input and output file format the same by setting `OFS=FS` (I used a `tab` in your file)

No need to zero `s`, just set `s=$1` and iterate over the rest `for (i=2;...`

Then if you `sprintf` your sum to `$(NF+1)` you can just default print `$0` with `OFS` (that's the `1` at the end).

```
1       2       3       4       2.5
3       3       8       8       5.5
5       4       13      12      8.5
7       5       18      16      11.5
9       6       23      20      14.5
11      7       28      24      17.5
13      8       33      28      20.5
15      9       38      32      23.5
17      10      43      36      26.5
19      11      48      40      29.5
21      12      53      44      32.5
23      13      58      48      35.5
25      14      63      52      38.5
```

Though you could also

```
awk '{s=$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; $(NF+1)=sprintf("%.1f", s/NF)}1' file | column -t
1   2   3   4   2.5
3   3   8   8   5.5
5   4   13  12  8.5
7   5   18  16  11.5
9   6   23  20  14.5
11  7   28  24  17.5
13  8   33  28  20.5
15  9   38  32  23.5
17  10  43  36  26.5
19  11  48  40  29.5
21  12  53  44  32.5
23  13  58  48  35.5
25  14  63  52  38.5
```